# Auto log off from external site in Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, login, website

After log in to Jet Airways site, i find the details, but even before I could read,the site automatically logs out. This is happening only in Chrome browser but not in IE or Firefox. Is there a way out. Can someone guide please.

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the site in "incognito mode" in chrome, if it works:

Install the ["Edit This Cookie" plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg) for chrome.

Using a normal chrome window (not incognito), when at the login page for Jet Airways, click the extension icon (a small cookie) top right of your browser, and click the rubbish bin icon top left of the window that appears.

This will clear all cookies relating to the site.  Exit chrome then start it back up and try again.